# How to center field_with_errors class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, css, devise

I've recently installed Devise, and I've got the sign-in form working as it should, displaying errors etc...

However, the sign-up form is acting very strange i.e when displaying errors they appear on the left side out of proportion with the rest of the app. Here is a screen shot to illustrate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXjKQ.png note: this only happens when there are errors, it is centered otherwise.

Now i've tried editing the field_with_errors CSS with the following:

```
.field_with_errors {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
text-align: center; }
```

And still, it remains on the left hand side. I have noticed that float: right; seems to move it to the right, but how can I get it in the center with the rest of the form?

field_with_errors seems pretty darn stubborn in CSS.

Comment: Sir @JamesBrewer you are a legend, that worked! last thing is the color  http://i.imgur.com/jYNmCW8.png any idea on how I can change that from red to white? 'background: white;' and 'background-color: white;' don't seem to work

Comment: I've deleted my comment and added an answer. Feel free to accept. I'm glad it worked out for you. Try posting your HTML and CSS to a site like pastie.org and I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center text then `text-align: center` will work, but in this case you wish to center an entire element and should therefore use `margin: auto auto` instead.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use flexbox

```
.my class {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
```